# Permanently modify boot menu on another drive (Solaris 11.2)

Tags: boot, solaris, grub2

I'm running Solaris 11.2 on a HP Proliant Microserver Gen8. Because of a limited number of hard drive slots, I have installed a SSD in the optical drive bay. Unfortunately, this SATA slot is not bootable (BIOS limitation).

So, I have installed Solaris 11.2 on the SSD (where it should run). To make booting to the SSD possible, I have also a SD card in the server and have installed a second instance of Solaris there, just to create the GRUB2 boot menu. When I start the server, I can edit manually the GRUB2 boot menu with the "e" key, modify the UUID of the boot drive and the server starts from the SSD (instead of SD card) as I planned. The line I modify looks like this:

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set-root 09bd12det2aag8ab
```

However, as I discovered, this has to be done every time when starting the server, which is not a good option. How can I modify the GRUB2 boot menu permanently to change the UUID, so that GRUB boots to the SSD drive instead of the SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the alternate SD Solaris instance and add the line to its `/rpool/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file.

Beware that the file might be overwritten by Solaris should your change something in the boot configuration of this Solaris instance using `bootadm` or similar.